# Is there a way to replace only a few numeric character to a date in R?

Tags: r, excel, date, numeric

So I was using this code in R:

```
excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(as.character(sheet1$col4)), date_system = "modern")
```

To replace all the numeric characters into dates from excel, which worked great! However I now have a sheet in which some dates are displaying as dates, and some are numbers. E.g.:

- 01/01/2020
- 38880
- 39239
- 02/02/2019
- etc..

Now when I use the same code, it changes the numbers but deletes the dates. Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate/Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689061/r-inconsistent-date-format/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inspiration from akrun's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689302/13095326), you could use `coalesce` to merge the results of `excel_numeric_to_date` from `janitor` and `dmy` from `lubridate`.

You could use `mdy` if that ends up being more appropriate for your actual data.

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
coalesce(excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(sheet1$col4)),
         dmy(sheet1$col4))
#[1] "2020-01-01" "2006-06-12" "2007-06-06" "2019-02-02"
```

**Sample Data**:

```
sheet1 <- structure(list(col4 = c("01/01/2020", "38880", "39239", "02/02/2019"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked! With Akrun's answer it didn't work somehow...