# Adjust date format in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like some help regarding the following question: the code below is running normally. It generates scatter plots if selected one of three dates from my `df database`. Until then OK.

As you can see the date of my `df database` is in yyyy-mm-dd format. However, if I insert a database in dd-mm-yyyy format it gives an error. Is there any way to standardize this?

I left two `df databases`, one with yyyy-mm-dd format and one with dd-mm-yyyy format for you to test.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

function.cl<-function(dt){
  df <- structure(
    list(date = c("2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01",
                  "2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08",
                  "2021-08-13","2021-08-13","2021-08-13","2021-08-13","2021-08-13"),
         Week= c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday",
                 "Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
         D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8), 
         DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
         DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
         DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
  
  
  # df <- structure(
  #   list(date = c("01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021",
  #                 "08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021",
  #                 "13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021"),
  #        Week= c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday",
  #                "Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
  #        D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8),
  #        DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
  #        DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  #        DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)),
  #   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

  
  scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
    dta %>%
      mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
      filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
      summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
      pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
      mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
      plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
  }  
  Plot1<-scatter_date(dt)
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = Plot1, 
    date = df$date
  ))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl("2021-08-01"))
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date)
    function.cl(input$date)[["Plot1"]]
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: There are packages that help if you are not able to fix the source of the problem (the source of the data: the best place to fix inconsistent date formatting is to get it right when the data is created): for instance `lubridate` and `anytime`. Neither of those are strictly necessary, one can iterate over candidate formats, such as a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689230/3358272) of mine.

Comment: But this question (how to deal with various date formats) really has nothing to do with [tag:shiny], I suggest you solve this on the R console and then port that solution into a `shiny` app.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @r2evans. I did wrong. I put the code in shiny because it was working, the only problem was regarding the date in dd-mm-yyyy format. But thanks for reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` and pass different formats that the date can take.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

function.cl<-function(dt){
  df <- structure(
       list(date = c("01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021","01-08-2021",
                     "08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021","08-08-2021",
                     "13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021","13-08-2021"),
            Week= c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday",
                    "Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
            D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8),
            DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
           DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7),
            DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)),
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
  
  df$date <- parse_date_time(df$date, c('ymd', 'dmy'))
  
  scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
    dta %>%
      filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
      summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
      pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
      mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
      plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
  }  
  Plot1<-scatter_date(dt)
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = Plot1, 
    date = df$date
  ))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl("2021-08-01"))
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date)
    function.cl(input$date)[["Plot1"]]
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ronak thanks for the reply. Are you sure it worked for you? Because for me it didn't. If it's not bothersome, you could put all the code, so it's easier for me to see if it's right.

Comment: Sorry, I did not test the entire application because I thought the question is about how to handle dates with different format. If you replace the two dataframes in your code with `df1` and `df2` and use the above function as `scatter_date('2021-08-01', df1)` and `scatter_date('2021-08-01', df2)`. It seems to work and give expected output. You can try it with different dates.

Comment: The way you said, I managed to generate the graph separately from the shiny one. But my idea is to show it on shiny, so what would my Plot1 look like, considering I'm only going to use the second database (df2). Can you help me? If you find it necessary, I can ask a new question. Thank you again.

Comment: Edited the answer to include complete code. Hope that helps.